# Passing argument to Go IIFE (following javascript example)

Tags: javascript, go, iife

I'm used to programming in javascript where I can do the following to pass an argument into an immediately-invoked function expression:

```
(function(twoSeconds) {
    // do something with "twoSeconds" here
})(2 * 1000);
```

So I expected to be able to do something similar in Go, as below. However, it doesn't seem to work.

```
func (twoSeconds) {
    // build error: "twoSeconds" undefined
}(time.Second * 2)
```

So I have to do this instead:

```
func () {
    twoSeconds := time.Second * 2
}()
```

Therefore, my question is how can I pass an argument into a Go IIFE? And if it's not possible, why not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Function arguments in Go need types. So do the following:

```
func(twoSeconds time.Duration) {
    // use twoSeconds
}(time.Second * 2)
```

Comment: Oh, of course, that's obvious now, I can't believe I missed that! Thanks for the help anyway, upvoted and accepted.